# JSON parsing produce incorrect result for Double datatype

Tags: ios, json, swift, double, data-conversion

I am trying to convert a class object to JSON string to display on screen but `Double` datatypes are getting wrong values.
Here is my code

```
struct Wallet: Codable {
  var balance: Double
  var limit: Double
  var currency: String
}

func showJSON() {
  let data = Wallet(balance: Double(200.24), limit: Double(5000), currency: "INR")
  let result = convertToJSONString(data)
  print(result!)
}

func convertToJSONString<T: Codable>(_ response: T) -> String? {
  var jsonString: String?
  let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
  jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
  if let data = try? jsonEncoder.encode(response) {
    jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
  }
  return jsonString
}

//function call
showJSON()
```

And my output is

```
{
  "balance" : 200.24000000000001,
  "limit" : 5000,
  "currency" : "INR"
}
```

Check the balance value here, we have provided 200.24 but after conversion it showing as 200.24000000000001. Can someone suggest what needs to be change here to have exact output?

> Note* - You can copy paste this code to playground directly, it will work without any modifications.

Comment: Floating points are not always accurate. If precision is important (which it probably is if you're talking about money), then use an integer (or long) (e.g. 20024 instead of 200.24) and show the decimal after the fact (like when you might convert it to a string, for example). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate#:~:text=Because%20often%2Dtimes%2C%20they%20are,many%20digits%20in%20any%20base.

Comment: In my case, decimal values are not fix it could be any digit and playing with balance can be tricky so wanted to have solution where I can just do conversion and show the response.

Comment: You mean you can have more decimal spaces than 2? Like 100.001?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it can .001 or .0001 or .1

Comment: Then you can allow yourself more decimal spaces. Like 200.24 could be represented as 200240000 and then you just divide the result by 1,000,000 to get the dollars and mod by 1,000,000 and divide by 10,000 to get the cents.

Comment: You can use a String for persisting the balance. Let's call it balanceString and have another computed property balance which is Double and can get from balanceString like `var balance: Double? { Double(balanceString) }`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Unfortunately we can't do round of in our case.

Comment: @David @Heaven - It's a big complex json having amount at multiple places so just wanted to have generic thing to parse and show the response on `UITextView` and we can't do the changes in source which populates the `Double` value.

Comment: I got the solution, adding same as answer below. It may helpful for others.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I can have desire output with using `JSONSerialization` and `Any` datatype. Check below added answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Devid commented above, floating points are not always accurate and conversion from `Double` or `Float` to `String` get impacted.

So, instate of doing conversion to `String` we can always hold JSON in `Any` datatype to print/show.

Basically, it won't do conversion so values wont get impacted.

Here, I Just replaced the `convertToJSONString` function in above implementation like

```
func convertToJSONString<T: Codable>(_ response: T) -> Any? {
  var jsonString: Any?
  let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
  jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
  if let data = try? jsonEncoder.encode(response) {
    jsonString = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
  }
  return jsonString
}
```

used `JSONSerialization` and getting output as

```
{
  balance = "200.24";
  currency = INR;
  limit = 5000;
}
```

It is useful to show big and complex JSON with original `Double` or `Float` values and to make use of it you can always hold them in relevant datatypes so values wont get impacted.

Comment: Which could be rewritten in 2 lines `guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(response) else { return nil }.  
    return try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Decimal` from `Foundation` instead of `Double`.

```swift
import Foundation

struct Wallet: Codable {
    var balance: Decimal
    var limit: Decimal
    var currency: String
}

func showJSON() {
    let data = Wallet(
        balance: Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: -2, significand: 20024),
        limit: 5000,
        currency: "INR"
    )
    let result = convertToJSONString(data)
    print(result!)
}

func convertToJSONString<T: Codable>(_ response: T) -> String? {
    var jsonString: String?
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    if let data = try? jsonEncoder.encode(response) {
        jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }
    return jsonString
}

//function call
showJSON()
```

Alternatively, you might wish to use a different multiple precision library. See [Swift-BigInt](https://github.com/mkrd/Swift-BigInt), [swift-numberkit](https://github.com/objecthub/swift-numberkit), or [BigInt](https://github.com/attaswift/BigInt). This will take more work though (you might need to make your own Decimal wrapper around these, or use a Rational type or something). Whatever you end up choosing, if you really require this much precision, make sure you have plenty of tests to make sure there aren't subtle issues somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for reply but I can't modify the souce datatype neither  do any processing for a single element. Above added data is just an example but in real usecase I am having a big and complex JSON having Double datatypes at many places. I have figure ourlt the way and added as answer here